# xdg-open keeps using Konqueror

Tags: xdg-open

```
$ xdg-settings --list
Known properties:
  default-url-scheme-handler    Default handler for URL scheme
  default-web-browser           Default web browser
$ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
google-chrome-beta.desktop
$ xdg-mime query default text/html
/usr/share/applications/google-chrome-beta.desktop
```

But when I run:

```
$ xdg-open my.html
```

It opens it in Konqueror. I'm using Xfce4 on Debian 9 "stretch". I have looked at I hope to all answers about `xdg-open` in the site but none apply to me. What should I check? Where should I look?

Comment: Which browser opens `exo-open --launch WebBrowser`

Comment: @Bahamut: `exo-open --launch WebBrowser` opens a new window in google-chrome.

Comment: Let us chitchat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59857/discussion-between-hynek-pichi-vychodil-and-bahamut This is intresting for me.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your html file has the mime type text/xml:

```
$ file my.html
my.html: XML 1.0 document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

Set the default application for opening XML files:

```
$ xdg-mime default firefox.desktop text/xml
```